# How to install jBox2d in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, libraries, box2d

I would like to make the game in Java with jBox2D. Unfortunately, I do not know how to install the necessary libraries to be able to use jBox2D.

I'm using NetBeans.

Comment: @Poitrek K: On StackOverflow, when an answer solved your question, you should accept it by clicking on the "tick" under the score of the question, it will color green. When it is green, you accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't "*install*" a library in an IDE, you configure the classpath for your project using your IDE.

Right click on your project in the "Projects" tab. Choose "Properties". In the tree at the left of the dialog, enter "Libraries". Then click the button at the left "Add JAR/Folder" and navigate to the library jar of JBox2D.

[image: Classpath Editor]

Comment: Thanks, but where can I find jBox2d tutorial?

Comment: If I remember well, I though Todd had made some tutorials. They were for Flash, but that doesn't matter. You have to know how the engine works. Yes, indeed: http://www.kerp.net/box2d/ Just follow all of them. But beware: `Lesson 2.26: Getting a platform to move -- the right way` isn't the right way of doing it. When you finally reach that video, you should mention that he should make it a kinematic body, instead of a dynamic body.